# YII Session with button

Tags: session, button, yii

I Have 3 buttons, for each button i want to make a session with different values
I have tried with this code

```
<?php
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonGroup', array(
'type' => 'primary',
'toggle' => 'radio', // 'checkbox' or 'radio'
'buttons' => array(
array(
'label' => 'Shift I',
'htmlOptions' => array('onclick' => Yii::app()->session['shift'] = 2),
),
array(
'label' => 'Shift II',
'htmlOptions' => array('onclick' => Yii::app()->session['shift'] = 2),
),
array(
'label' => 'Shift III',
'htmlOptions' => array('onclick' => Yii::app()->session['shift'] = 3),
),
),
));
?>
```

but it always use the session number 3..
how to fix it??
I use Yii-Bootstrap,

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning your session each time you do:

```
'htmlOptions' => array('onclick' => Yii::app()->session['shift'] = 2),
```

lets look closer, in above you have `Yii::app()->session['shift'] = 1`
which will assign value 1, to your sesson variable,

you are doind this 3 TIMES!

which means you are assigning that same variable 3 different values, and the last assignment is 3!

try doing an ajax request to a controller,with the parameters you want and then change session variable in here.

Comment: but i put it in the click button..do you have any suggestion??

Comment: don't make it complicated, put a call to a javascript function on that onclick and send your parameters to a controller to handle that. api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax

Comment: dou have any example how to do that..?? thanks before

Comment: I think that would be another question,right? did you find answer for this question?

Answer (score -1):

Try using in this way

```
<?php
$val1 = array("2");
$val2 = array("3");
$val3 = array("4");
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonGroup', array(
'type' => 'primary',
'toggle' => 'radio', // 'checkbox' or 'radio'
'buttons' => array(
array(
'label' => 'Shift I',
'htmlOptions' => array('onclick' => Yii::app()->session['shift'] = $val1),
),
array(
'label' => 'Shift II',
'htmlOptions' => array('onclick' => Yii::app()->session['shift'] = $val2),
),
array(
'label' => 'Shift III',
'htmlOptions' => array('onclick' => Yii::app()->session['shift'] = $val3),
),
),
));
?>
```

Comment: Indirect modification of overloaded element of CHttpSession has no effect
It's Error

Comment: and How can i get the value..?? 
i use <?php echo Yii::app()->session['shift']; ?> and i get Error

Comment: this is clearly wrong, neither assigning 3 times, nor echoing it in assignment! please read my answer